# Who is the celestial being appears at Dasaratha's Putra Kameshti Yagna?

Tags: ramayana, identification-request, devatas

Most of us know that a celestial being appears at Dasaratha's Putra Kameshti Yagna. But, Who actually he is?

(**Note: For help, you can find is if any deity's appearance is totally same as this guy and his appearance is mentioned in [here](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga16/bala_16_frame.htm)**)